# Sending variable calculated with <input type="range"> (sliders) to Paypal button's price value <input type="hidden" name="amount">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, paypal

I'm trying to send variable calculated with multiple  (sliders) to Paypal in order to make a dynamic button whose price value changes depending on the slider values.

So far I have managed to take the calculated value out of the form as variable in javascript (var = mapoman). But I have been failing to pass the value to Paypal button... I'm using an unhosted Paypal button.

I assume the calculated value is stored in input, is that right??
Currently oninput in form calculates for displaying through output and function Add() calculates the value for Paypal button...

I cannot use PHP as my server does not handle it at the moment. So I'm trying to achieve this only using javascript.

The below is my code..
I really hope it's doable!!
I appreciate any advice, thanks!

```
<html>

<head>

<script language="javascript">

function Add(){
document.mapo.mapoprice.value = eval(document.mapo.slider1.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider2.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider3.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider4.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider5.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider6.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider7.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider8.value);
}

function GetMapoman(){
var mapoman = document.getElementById("mapoprice").value;
document.getElementById("saru").innerHTML = mapoman; 
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<form name="mapo" oninput="total.value = slider1.valueAsNumber + slider2.valueAsNumber + slider3.valueAsNumber + slider4.valueAsNumber + slider5.valueAsNumber + slider6.valueAsNumber + slider7.valueAsNumber + slider8.valueAsNumber;Add();GetMapoman();">

<input name="slider1" id="slider1" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider2" id="slider2" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider3" id="slider3" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider4" id="slider4" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider5" id="slider5" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider6" id="slider6" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider7" id="slider7" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input name="slider8" id="slider8" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px">

<input type="text" name="mapoprice" id="mapoprice"><!-- <--is this storing the value calculated by the sliders above???-->
<output name="total" for="slider1 slider2 slider3 slider4 slider5 slider6 slider7 slider8"></output>

</form>

<p id="saru"></p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="---.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="---">
<input type="hidden" name="amount id="totalmapo"><!--this bit I'm trying to put the calculated value by the sliders-->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what issue do you face here?

Comment: hi, the issue is i cannot pass the value calculated with sliders to paypal's value (price). i have been trying many methods that were suggested in stackoverflow but haven't managed to figure it out yet...

Comment: you can check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many trials and errors, I finally managed to realise the function I wanted without jquery.

```
    <html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" >

function Add(){
document.mapo.mapoprice.value = eval(document.mapo.slider1.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider2.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider3.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider4.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider5.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider6.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider7.value) + eval(document.mapo.slider8.value);
}

function GetMapoman(){
var mapoman = document.getElementById("mapoprice").value;
document.getElementById("saru").innerHTML = mapoman; 
}

function updateTextInput1(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput1').value=val; 
    }

function updateTextInput2(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput2').value=val; 
    }

function updateTextInput3(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput3').value=val; 
    }

function updateTextInput4(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput4').value=val; 
    }

function updateTextInput5(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput5').value=val; 
    }

function updateTextInput6(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput6').value=val; 
    }    

function updateTextInput7(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput7').value=val; 
    }    

function updateTextInput8(val) {
      document.getElementById('textInput8').value=val; 
    }    

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="mapo" id="mapo" oninput="Add();GetMapoman();GetMapomanPrice();">

<input name="slider1" id="slider1" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput1(this.value);" oninput="amount1.value=slider1.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput1" value="">
<output name="amount1" for="slider1">3</output>

<input name="slider2" id="slider2" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput2(this.value);" oninput="amount2.value=slider2.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput2" value="">
<output name="amount2" for="slider2">3</output>

<input name="slider3" id="slider3" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput3(this.value);" oninput="amount3.value=slider3.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput3" value="">
<output name="amount3" for="slider3">3</output>

<input name="slider4" id="slider4" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput4(this.value);" oninput="amount4.value=slider4.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput4" value="">
<output name="amount4" for="slider4">3</output>

<input name="slider5" id="slider5" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput5(this.value);" oninput="amount5.value=slider5.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput5" value="">
<output name="amount5" for="slider5">3</output>

<input name="slider6" id="slider6" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput6(this.value);" oninput="amount6.value=slider6.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput6" value="">
<output name="amount6" for="slider6">3</output>

<input name="slider7" id="slider7" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput7(this.value);" oninput="amount7.value=slider7.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput7" value="">
<output name="amount7" for="slider7">3</output>

<input name="slider8" id="slider8" type="range" min="3" max="8" value="3" step="1" style="width:650px" onchange="updateTextInput8(this.value);" oninput="amount8.value=slider8.value">
<input type="text" id="textInput8" value="">
<output name="amount8" for="slider8">3</output>

<p><input type="text" name="mapoprice" value="" id="mapoprice" /></p>

</form>

<p id="saru"></p>

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="---.com"><!--put your own email address-->
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="---"><!--put your own item name-->
<input type="hidden" name="amount" id="finalpaypal">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

<script>
function GetMapomanPrice() { 
var mapoman = document.getElementById("mapoprice").value;
document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = mapoman;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
      range: "max",
      min: 1,
      max: 10,
      value: 2,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
          $( "#amt_id" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed maximum</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    </head>
  <body>
  <label for="amount">Choose an Amount</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
  <br><br>      
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="vimal.android@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
    <input id="amt_id" type="hidden" name="amount" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Here you go: **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8owze31/2/)**

I am not sure I understand your code, but I have used simple jquery slider to dynamically pass item amount to PayPal.

P.S I used Jquery which I think should be easy to do the slider.

Comment: thanks, Vimal, it looks great but I'm a novice in coding so cannot figure out how to run it right... would you be able to show which bit of your code to put in (head),(body) and so on?

Comment: and one more thing, do you know how to make multiple sliders with this jquery slider and send the added up value to paypal?

Comment: just see the JSFiddle link, you will see where to put what

Comment: just copy the above code, save as .html file and run, thats it

Comment: I figured out that I had to load jquery first then jquery ui and jquery css. I think I can alter it and achieve what I wanted to make. thanks!

Comment: Stack overflow is a place where you get technical help on your issues, not on `how to teach you programming`, glad you figured it out by yourself.

Comment: Hi Vimal, thanks for your support, your code definitely helped me think more deeply about how javascript/jquery works. I'm new to stackoverflow but I'm hoping to keep learning with this community. thanks a lot!